# When I'm trying to compile the Protobuf in golang, It's showing '"int" is not defined.'

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, protobuf-java, protobuf-c, protobuf-go

While compiling the proto file, I'm getting '"int" is not defined'.

'test.proto' file

```golang
syntax = "proto3";

package test;

option go_package = "/;test";

message User {
    string FirstName = 1;
    string LastName = 2;
    string Address = 3;
    int Contact = 4;
    int Age = 5;
}
```

```
Output:
test.proto:11:5: "int" is not defined.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`int` is not a scalar type in proto3. You must use one of the valid scalar value types as specified:

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#scalar

Replacing `int` with `int32`:

```golang
syntax = "proto3";

package test;

option go_package = "/;test";

message User {
    string FirstName = 1;
    string LastName = 2;
    string Address = 3;
    int32 Contact = 4;
    int32 Age = 5;
}
```